# How can I use powershell to list only the strings in a log file created in the last 3 hours?

Tags: powershell, datetime, grep, gawk

I have a log file where dates and corresponding information are listed in strings with a format of:

```
Tuesday, July 14, 2015 4:44:03 PM
Order Number 001006
Credit Card Type: AX
MessageType: 0100
Bit  2 [Primary_Account_Number..................] 3797*******1000
Bit  3 [Processing_Code.........................] 200000
Bit  4 [Amount_of_Transaction...................]     2.40
Bit 11 [Debit_Reg_E_Receipt_Number..............] 000083
Bit 14 [Expiration_Date.........................] 1704
Bit 18 [Merchant_Category_Code..................] 5812
Bit 22 [POS_Entry_Mode_PIN_Capability...........] 011
Bit 24 [Network_International_ID_NII............] 001
Bit 25 [POS_Condition_Code......................] 00
Bit 31 [Acquirer_Reference_Data.................] 2
Bit 37 [Retrieval_Reference_Number..............] 000000000283
Bit 41 [Terminal_ID.............................] 04765035
Bit 42 [Merchant_ID.............................] 000425249820993
Bit 59 [Merchant_ZIP_Postal_Code................] 19004

Tuesday, July 14, 2015 4:44:07 PM : Response:
Order Number 
Credit Card Type:   
MessageType: 0110
Bit  3 [Processing_Code.........................] 200000
Bit  4 [Amount_of_Transaction...................] 000000000240
Bit  7 [Transmission_Date_Time..................] 0714234410
Bit 11 [Debit_Reg_E_Receipt_Number..............] 000083
Bit 24 [Network_International_ID_NII............] 0001
Bit 25 [POS_Condition_Code......................] 00
Bit 37 [Retrieval_Reference_Number..............] 000000000283
Bit 39 [Response_Code...........................] 00
Bit 41 [Terminal_ID.............................] 04765035
Table 14
N                     000000000000000000000240

Table 22
APPROVAL
```

This log is constantly updated, but I would like to get the current date/time and display only the information in the log from 3 hours ago, to present. I need all the information in the log, just not anything prior to Tuesday, July 14, 2015 1:44:03 (as an example). Is there some way I can get the current date/time and parse the log file for 3 hours prior to get the information I need? Maybe using Powershell or some sort of windows port of unix commands? The goal is to create a script that essentially truncates a log to display the past 3 hours of activity, and output that into a new log. I hope I stated this clearly enough. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this could be done in PowerShell, Could you post more of a sample of your source file (or mock up a sample that we could see with fake but realistic data)? PS could probably split the data into records, and then just display the records that are `[datetime]::now.AddHours(-3)` or newer.

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, PowerShell can do that. Give me a minute to write up an answer and I think I can do a little better than the one already posted.

Comment: Are the messages always separated by an empty line?

Comment: There are two empty lines within the blocks of information. Each block begins with a Date/Time string. Between each block, however, there are two empty lines. That is the distinguishing trait between the blocks of information... 2 empty lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer as you updated your post :

```
$path = 'C:\list.txt'
$file = Get-Content $path
$i = 0

$before = (Get-Date).AddHours(-3)

foreach ($line in $file)
{
    $i++

    if ($line -match ', 2015 ')
    {
        $date = [regex]::match($line,'(?<=day, )(.*\n?)(?<=M)').value | Get-Date

        if ($date -ge $before)
        {
            (Get-Content $path) | Select -Skip $($i-1)
            Break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This script processes for a bit without error, however nothing is displayed. Do I need to output this to something?

Comment: It is normal because your example have the date of July 14, 2015 and you run the script on July 16 searching the last 3 hours. Just take your example and change the date, for example the 1st Thursday, July 16, 2015 8:44:03 PM and the 2nd Thursday, July 16, 2015 8:44:04 PM

Comment: Did you tested this solution?

Comment: I apologize, I'm somewhat new to PS and did not know where to change the variables. Regardless, I need the script to get the current Date/Time, parse the log for the last Date/Time string, take the current time -3 hours and find the closest Date/Time string in the log, then select everything in between. I need the script to run without having to define any variables. Not sure if that all made sense, if not I can try to clarify. I appreciate the continued help

Comment: My script doesn't require to change any variables. And it converts from string to datetime. With your example test it works.

Comment: I was able to get this to work. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this will set a boolean variable `$NewLogs` to `$false`. Then it reads your log file and for each line it checks to see if that `$NewLogs` has been set to `$true`, or if a date string is found, and if that date string is less than 3 hours old. If either the `$NewLogs` condition or the date string condition resolve to true, then it sets `$NewLogs` to `$true` (to make everything go faster for all lines past the current), and it passes that line through the pipeline. Then since `$NewLogs` is now `$true` all lines past that one will be passed through the pipeline.

```
$NewLogs = $false
Get-Content C:\Path\To\LogFile.txt -ReadCount 1000 |
    ForEach{
        If($NewLogs -or ($_ -match "(\S+day, \w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2} \w{2})" -and ([datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],"dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt",$null)) -gt [datetime]::Now.AddHours(-3))){$NewLogs=$true;$_}
    }
```

Then you can just pipe that to a `Set-Content` command to output to a new file, or leave it as is to display it on the screen. If it were me I'd probably change that very last line to:

```
    } | Set-Content (join-path 'C:\Path\To\' ([datetime]::now.tostring('MMddyyhhmmtt.\tx\t')))
```

So if I did that right now it would save the last 3 hours of logs to the file:

```
C:\Path\To\0715150359PM.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the powershell version in use makes any kind of difference, but I'm receiving an error of: Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Scripts_Tools\FDLog-3hr.ps1:4 char:12
+         If($NewLogs -or ($_ -match "(\S+day, \w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: Hm, I'm on Win8.1 running PS v4 and ran it without issues (I didn't output the file, but you aren't even making it that far).

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 SP1, and I installed Powershell v4.. still no luck. I will try to investigate. Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error about null array on Powershell v4 with the solution of TheMadTechnician, but doing the following works :

Remember to change the dates to

```
Thursday, July 16, 2015 8:44:03 PM
Thursday, July 16, 2015 8:44:04 PM
```

The updated script :

```
$NewLogs = $false
$file = Get-Content C:\list.txt -ReadCount 1000

foreach ($line in $file)
{
    If($NewLogs -or ($line -match '(\S+day, \w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2} \w{2})' -and ([datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],'dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt',$null)) -gt [datetime]::Now.AddHours(-3)))
    {
        $NewLogs = $true
        $line
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your modified script, but received:  Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:6 char:8
+     If($NewLogs -or ($line -match '(\S+day, \w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: Do you have an english version of Windows? Or another language (spanish, ...)?

Comment: It is Windows 7 Pro w/SP1 English